# Use object property as array key

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a PHP array of objects, say with two properties `a` and `b`. So for example I can do

```
$arr['a1']->a = $z;
$x = $arr['a1']->b;
```

The array is currently using the value of each object's `a` property as the array key, e.g.

```
$arr['a1']->a == 'a1'
```

This is so I can quickly look up the object by that property. I now need to quickly look up by `b`, and so want to switch the keys from being set to property `a` to being set to `b` (both are unique).

Is there an easy way to do this? In-place or into another array are both fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $object)
{
    $arr2[$object->b] = $object;
}
```

This will create a new array that points to the same objects.

If you want them in one array, you can do as Joost suggested in the comments (`$arr[$object->b] = $object;` in the loop instead). However, that will only work if there are no duplicate keys between the two sets.

Comment: Or even point to the same object with both keys ->a and ->b, assuming they are of different types or ranges..

Comment: @Joost, would that be as simple as doing `$arr2[$object->b] = &$object;` instead?

Comment: I actually ment `$arr[$object->b] = $object` rather than `$arr2`.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that would work provided the two properties combined are 100% unique, otherwise there may be some problems with an element in b over lapping an element in a.

Comment: Exactly. One would have to make sure they're of different types, or at least not in the same range.

Comment: It's a slow morning for me, monday as usual. Objects are passed as references anyway so my comment on using `&$` was pretty moot. I've updated the answer to make more sense.